# Is there a guide on creating graphs in Latex for signal processing?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, plot

I wish to create a graph commonly used in signal processing, for example:
[image]

I am not sure if I should go about exploiting Tikz or use some other software to generate this plot. Does anyone know if there is a guide on creating plots for signal processing (i.e. graph of periodic signals)?

If not, what other software would be recommended for this purpose?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe have a look at the iso-31... Euler's, the imaginary number and pi are mathematical constants and should be set upright. The index c (for cut-off) should be upright, too. Additionally, it might be a good idea to norm the axis to `\Omega = \omega _\ \omega_\mathrm{c}`. Italic letters are used for physical constant's, ie. an italic (`$e$ `) denotes the elementary charge.

Comment: There is also a [tikz-timing](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-timing) package that should do exactly what you're looking for,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**With tikz**

Here we can change width of pulses with `\omegac` set to `2` in this case.

We create two loops for putting nodes `-2\pi`, `2\pi`, `-\omega_c`,`\omega_c` and a loop for drawing pulse

You can reduce size of  picture with option `scale=0.5`

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\def\omegac{2} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% draw axis
\draw (-10,0)--(10,0)node[below]{$\omega$};
\draw (0,0)--(0,3)node[right]{$H(e^{j\omega})$};
\node [above right]at (0,1){$1$};

% putting nodes -2\pi , 2\pi 
\foreach \i/\j in {-2*pi/-2\pi,2*pi/2\pi}
{\draw (\i,0.2)--(\i,0)node[below]{$\j$};}

% draw path for each pulse 
\foreach \n in {-2*pi,0,2*pi}
{\draw[thick,blue](\n,0)++(-\omegac,0)--++(0,1)--++(2*\omegac,0)--++(0,-1);}

% putting nodes -\omega_c , \omega_c
\foreach \i/\j in {-\omegac/-,\omegac/}
{\node[below]at(\i,0){$\j\omega_c$};}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Your image doesn't quite correspond to the code posted. The image is missing the "1" at `(0,1)`.

Comment: I have updated  image.

Comment: @salimbou Hi thank you so much for your help. Do you know any good resource to teach you how to create these signal processing plots from Tikz and control diagrams of the type: u ->[ c(s) ] -> [ p(s) ] -> y

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest you to use [`pgfplots`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots); it offers you a lot of useful features to draw plots:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  typeset ticklabels with strut,
  width=10cm,
  height=3cm,
  axis lines=center,
  x axis line style={-},
  y axis line style={-},
  ymax = 3,
  xmin=-16,
  xmax=16,
  xtick={-10,-2,2,10},
  xticklabels={$-2\pi$,$-\omega_{c}$,$\omega_{c}$,$2\pi$},
  ytick={\empty},
  xlabel={$\omega$},
  ylabel={$H(e^{j\omega})$},
]

\foreach \Valor in {-10,0,10}
{
\addplot+[ultra thick,black,mark=none,const plot] 
  coordinates {(\Valor-2,0) (\Valor-2,1) (\Valor+2,0)};
}
\node[above left] at (axis cs:0,1) {1};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```